# I am trying to build a barcode generator with python to generate multiple barcodes from a csv file?

Tags: python, tkinter

i only found how to generate one barcode at a time, and also i didn't find a way to print it in labels straight from the program,

im still new to python and tkinter so if someone can help me i would appreciate it,
thank you

So I know how to generate one barcode but I don’t know how to generate multiple barcodes at one time and print it as a label and not to save it on my computer as a png, first I tried converting the csv file into a python list and I was going to generate that list but it’s still not working

Comment: Hey Sam, how exactly can we help? do you need a hand reading csv files, generating and saving multiple files? etc

Comment: How can we help without a [mre] and the full error traceback if any?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.